How can I update available inventory in a form based on previous form submissions?
I am creating a Cognito form for ticket sales. I want to be able to use a starting ticket inventory that gets updated as tickets are purchased.
For example, if the ticket inventory starts at 25, and a user purchases 2 tickets, the remaining inventory for future visitors would be 23 tickets, and that would be the maximum that the next user would be allowed to purchase until the inventory reached 0.
If I use a Calculation field, the inventory isn't updated for future visitors.
I don't know which way to go with this.
